# Spring Integration - TCP Client working on Windows but unable receive data in unix

Tags: spring-integration

I have created a TCP client in spring boot with using two direct channel, one for input stream or for out stream.
Issue is when I am running it in Windows and connect with a stand alone server which send and receive data to client then it works fine. BUT when I move the jars to Unix, client send data which server receives but when server send data back to client it won't received.

Any Idea?
How can i configure Gateway for this purpose using spring boot configuration.

Comment: You need to show the connection factory configuration so we can see what (de)serializers you have configured. Adding the client code would help too.

Answer (score 0):

With the leak of information and configuration we only can make an assumption that the problem is with message delimiter. By default this is used in the `AbstactConnectionFactory`:

```
private volatile Deserializer<?> deserializer = new ByteArrayCrLfSerializer();

private volatile Serializer<?> serializer = new ByteArrayCrLfSerializer();
```

This `ByteArrayCrLfSerializer` is based on the `private static final byte[] CRLF = "\r\n".getBytes();` messages delimiter.

So, it might be just a fact that your server sends a message with a delimiter which is not understood by the client.

See more info about this type of codec in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#message-demarcation-serializers-and-deserializers

Comment: Thanks @gary /@Artem.Will share code in some time. But I hv not configured any serialized/de serialized., Is it mandatory/required to set such? Also help me to understand for such scenario is it good to add gateway??

Comment: Wait. I’ve just mentioned in my answer what is default, when you don’t configure it yourself. Does it make sense for you? Not sure what is with “add gateway”, but receive and send is indeed about TCP Inbound Gateway.

Comment: thanks.. I just completely misunderstood default in ur answer.. my bad.